# How to find points on smaller inner circle based on outer circle intersections?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Given a circle of radius $r$ with two points: $x_1y_1, x_2y_2$, That are separated by angle $\theta$, how do I find similar points along the original rays for an inner circle with a smaller radius $r_1$?  In the image below, how would one find points $x_3y_3,x_4y_4$ based on knowing the larger circle's information? [image: points on inner circle]

**Given:**
$x_1y_1,x_2y_2$,$r$, $r_1$, $\theta$

**Find:** $x_3y_3,x_4y_4$

Comment: To be clear, we are given $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,r,t$ and we need to find $x_3,y_3,x_4,y_4$, right?

Comment: Yes, but also r1.  So we are given  x1,y1, x2,y2, r, r1, and t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to consider the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$, some data are redundant.

Let also assume without loss of generality that the origin of the coordinate system lies at the centre of the circumferences, this could be accomodated by a shift.
The points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ lie on a line through the centre, so $$ \frac{x_1}{x_3} = \frac{y_1}{y_3}  = \frac{r}{r_1} $$ which suffices to determine $(x_3,y_3)$ given the radii $r$ and $r_1$.
Same for $(x_4,y_4)$ from $(x_2,y_2)$

Comment: It seems the trees were blocking my view of the forest again.  What implication is it if the origin of the coordinate system is NOT at the centre of the circumferences?

Comment: Well the proportion argument gets endangered. What if the coordinate system is such that $x_3 = 0$, for example?